# Why would hostname -I report 3 IP addresses?

Tags: ip, ipv4

**Environment:** Fresh install of CentOS 8, Digital Ocean Droplet

**Question:** Why would `hostname -I` report 3 IP addresses?  Shouldn't it show 1 IPv4 and 1 IPv6 address?

**My Output:** (IP addresses changed)

149.50.50.1 10.10.10.1 2500:1111:1111:1111:1111:1111:1111

149.50.50.1 and 2500:1111:1111:1111:1111:1111:1111 are displayed in my DO control panel.  I have no idea where 10.10.10.1 comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

third address i think serve for management by Digital Ocean panel or something.
you can use:

```
ip -c a
```

to determine to what interface it binds.
and

```
nmtui
```

for setup network, if you are sure that 10.10.10.1 not used for anything - remove it from interface.